# Simplify $\frac {2\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-2-x} {x^2} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

In order to find the limit of the function at $0$ I need to simplify the fraction $$\frac {2\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-(2+x)} {x^2} $$
so that at $0$ it didn't look like $\frac 0 0$. I'm almost certain that it can be solved with a clever substitution of the variable but I didn't manage to find one.

I've also tried multiplying numerator and denominator by $2\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+2+x$, but without any success.

Comment: If you're not attached to doing this with a clever simplification, it's straightforward with L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: *multiplying numerator and denominator by...* works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiplying numerator and denominator by $$2\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+2+x$$ we get
after simplification $$\frac{3x^2}{x^2(2\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+2+x)}$$ and after cancelling $$x^2$$ you will get the searched limit.

Comment: Right, I made a mistake while unfolding $(x+2)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. By Taylor expansion, it is easy to see that for $t\to 0$, 
$$\sqrt{1+t}=1+\frac{t}{2}-\frac{t^2}{8}+o(t^2).$$
Hence
$$2\sqrt{x^2+x+1}=2\sqrt{1+(x+x^2)}=2+x+x^2-\frac{(x+x^2)^2}{4}+o((x+x^2)^2)\\=2+x+\frac{3}{4}x^2+o(x^2).
$$